# How do you integrate with the SharePoint search box autocomplete?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

We are using the Set-PnPSearchSettings to customize our search

What are the integration capabilities with regards to the search bar dropdown?

At the moment a user has to type their query in and hit enter or click the magnifier icon before they can see results

How can we show results in the dropdown?

[image]

Comment: It depends on the level of search that you are using. Please read the below: https://www.mrsharepoint.guru/sharepoint-search-levels/ 
Search functions differently when you browse a site collection or a document library/list. it is basically a multilevel functionality that parses different results based on where you currently are.

Comment: @jimas13 I'm using Set-PnPSearchSettings to integrate with my own custom search data source but I can't seem to get the autocomplete to work at all at any level with my data source

Comment: can you please make sure that the Query Suggestion here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-query-suggestions#to-create-query-suggestions-in-sharepoint-search is set to enabled?

Comment: @jimas13 yes "Show search suggestions" is checked. It looks like maybe this is an oversight of the PnpSearchSettings feature?

Comment: Once you click on the search input there should be a GET http request that fetches all of the suggestion and previous searches. You can locate it in the dev tools of the browser and it should look like this : https://<your-tenant>.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext=%27(*)%27&querytemplate...... does that get request get any responses ???

Comment: There is no request occuring on the page, but I do get an XML result when I go direct to that URL. Perhaps the PnpSearchSettings is disabling that request from occuring?

Comment: well... it might and it might not... it's kinda strange since the search on top of the navbar is delivered as OOB functionality. I think that your best bet would be a ticket directly to MS and just a last question : Does the same behaviour occur when you use the search bar on https://portal.office.com? this should fetch results from all of the o365 services, not just sharepoint...

Comment: @jimas13 okay I'll try logging a ticket - I did already ask on their forum but no response - I don't actually get a search bar on portal.office.com, but I do get one at https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx which does do autocomplete

Comment: taken from here : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-what-you-need-with-microsoft-search-d5ed5d11-9e5d-4f1d-b8b4-3d371fe0cb87 where it states that "When you’re signed in to Microsoft 365, you’ll find the new Microsoft Search box at the top of several of the apps in Microsoft 365. It looks like this...." the fourth option on the image should be the portal search bar.... i havent come across a tenant that didnt have one. Contact MS and leave an answer so that if anyone comes across this problem might get a solution :)